# How to get list of objects from entity which has same object in it? - ios

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have this DB structure in my `CoreData`. I need to get list of all `Task` objects in `Task` entity which has same `Group` object (i.e. group contains these tasks which I want to get). How I can do that with `Predicates` or something else?
[image]

I tried this code:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Task", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdate", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "group.createdate == %@", group!.createdate)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Details")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the group you need to filter by (I think it is "`group`" in your code). Make sure it is a valid object or you will get a crash after unwrapping with `!`.  Add a predicate to your fetched results controller like this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"group = %@", group)
```

That's all ;-).

Comment: Ah yeah. Didn't realise it was for an frc.

Comment: Daaamn. I tried same but "group == %@". Thanks a lot!!